# Xtext UI model validation and messaging via markers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

Currently I have some validation in the main project which the UI project interprets as markers. I would like move that validation from the main project to the UI project, so that the parser is not concerned about it. Also I would like to add validations and marker messaging which need some data from preferences, so these have to be in the UI project as well, aimed to enrich the UI experience. What is the best way to plug in several model validations (preferably separate) which would get the marker-displaying support of Xtext?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. The validation is part of your model. If you move it to the UI plugin, other EMF tools can access your model without being bound to the validation and could create invalid models (because they do not trigger your validations).

Preference *pages* are shown in UI plugins, but preference *values* are stored in so called [preference stores](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_load_and_save_plug-in_preferences%3F), which are accessible from non UI plugins. Therefore using preferences to tune validations is no reason to move them to the UI plugin.

Comment: I want the model to be valid even without the validation (in fact it's not a validation for me, but rather a way to communicate with the user and help him write the model in the GUI editor). If there is more appropriate way not involving the word "valid", please tell me.